# Decorate class which inherits from concrete class(es)

Tags: design-patterns, c++, multiple-inheritance, decorator

In my project I have several "basic" interfaces whose behavior is fixed, i.e. the default implementation will always be good for every puropse. So I defined them as concrete classes with data members, `Configurable`, `Named`, `DataUser` etc., e.g.:

```cpp
class Configurable {
public:
  void SetParameter(int i) { _prop = i; }
  int GetParameter() { return _prop; }
private:
  int _prop;
};
```

For complex classes which I want to manipulate also using the basic interfaces I define a multiple inheritance:

```
class Algorithm: public Configurable, public Named, public DataUser {
public:
  virtual ~Algorithm() = default;
  virtual void Process() = 0;
};
```

Now I have the need to decorate a complex class, e.g.:

```
class AlgorithmDecorator: public Algorithm{
public:
  AlgorithmDecorator(std::unique_ptr<Algorithm> &&algo): _algo{std::move(algo)} {}
  void Process() { _algo->Process(); /* decoration code here */}
protected:
  std::unique_ptr<Algorithm> _algo;
};
```

and in doing this I'm not interested in decorating the behavior of the basic classes. But obviously doing like above any call to a method of a basic class for a decorator object will work on the basic class representation of the decorator, not that of `_algo`, e.g.:

```
class ConcreteAlgorithm: public Algorithm {
public:
  void Process() { std::cout << GetParameter() << std::endl; }
}

int main() {
  std::unique_ptr<algorithm> algo = std::make_unique<ConcreteAlgorithm>();
  algo = std::make_unique<AlgorithmDecorator>(std::move(algo));
  algo->SetParameter(5);
  algo->Process();
  return 0;
}
```

The actual output is 0, since the parameter value is set for the decorator instance and not for the wrapped algorithm. This could be solved by making `Configurable::SetParameter` virtual and overriding it in `AlgorithmDecorator` setting the parameter value both for the decorator instance and for `_algo`, but then these two must be kept in sync for consistency. Having two representations playing here is definitely a major problem.

This "double representation" creates several problems other than this, so I ended up with a single, shared representation implementation of `Configurable`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

class Configurable {
public:
  Configurable() : _repr{std::make_shared<Representation>()} {}
  void SetParameter(int i) { _repr->_prop = i; }
  int GetParameter() { return _repr->_prop; }

protected:
  class Representation {
    friend class Configurable;
    int _prop;
  };
  Configurable(const std::shared_ptr<Representation> &repr) : _repr{repr} {}
  std::shared_ptr<Representation> &GetRepresentation() { return _repr; }

private:
  std::shared_ptr<Representation> _repr;
};

class AlgorithmDecorator;
class Algorithm : public Configurable {
public:
  Algorithm() {}
  virtual ~Algorithm() = default;
  virtual void Process() = 0;

protected:
  friend AlgorithmDecorator;
  Algorithm(std::shared_ptr<Configurable::Representation> &repr) : Configurable(repr) {}
};

class AlgorithmDecorator : public Algorithm {
public:
  AlgorithmDecorator(std::unique_ptr<Algorithm> &&algo)
      : Algorithm(algo->Configurable::GetRepresentation()), _algo{std::move(algo)} {}
  void Process() { _algo->Process(); std::cout << "Decorated" << std::endl; }

protected:
  std::unique_ptr<Algorithm> _algo;
};

class ConcreteAlgorithm : public Algorithm {
public:
  void Process() { std::cout << GetParameter() << std::endl; }
};

int main() {
  std::unique_ptr<Algorithm> algo = std::make_unique<ConcreteAlgorithm>();
  algo = std::make_unique<AlgorithmDecorator>(std::move(algo));
  algo->SetParameter(5);
  algo->Process();
  return 0;
}
```

This works, but seems awkward and scales quite poorly when inheriting `Algorithm` form several basic classes.

All of this makes me think about a bad design, but I can't come up with a better solution that:

1. does not force me to duplicate the default implementation of basic classes in every complex class (`Algorithm` is just one of the many complex classes in my project);
2. makes the decorator work as expected, i.e. just add functionalities with no need to care about the underlying representation.

Any hint about how to improve this or on a different pattern that might do the job better is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Assuming that the `Algorithm`-specific interface is enough for the client code, make `Algorithm` pure virtual, and don't inherit the other classes (Configurable, Named, DataUser); then create a `AlgorithmBase` that inherits all of them (Algorithm, Configurable, Named, DataUser), and derive your ConcreteAlgorithm(s) from that. Derive decorators from the bare bones pure virtual `Algorithm` only, then compose the decorated object and use in clients through the `Algorithm` interface.

Comment: This would mean to implement in the decorator class the redirection to all the methods of the basic objects in the composition, right? I initially discarded this option since it requires a lot of boilerplate work plus also splitting all of the basic classes in an interface plus a base concrete implementation. But maybe it's the most architecturally correct way to obtain the desired behavior... I'll give it a try, thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: No, what I meant by "Assuming that the `Algorithm`-specific interface is enough for the client code" was: if it's the case that at the call site (where you use the decorated object) you don't need any methods other than those defined on the bare-bones `Algorithm` interface (in the scenario I proposed based on your example, this would just be the `Process()` method), then `Algorithm` as I suggested it serves to segregate a subset of the full interface, and then you can build a decorator over that subset (no need to redirect or expose any other methods). 1/2

Comment: Yes, the decorator is meant to be a transparent wrapper over some other interface, but following the Interface Segregation Principle (ISP), you can have different "views" of your class in different clients (you don't have to expose the same set of methods to every consumer). If at the place where you need to decorate the class you only require a narrower interface, segregate that out, and only decorate that - that's a perfectly valid Decorator pattern implementation. Now, I don't know enough about your specific use case, so this might not work for you, but it's an approach to consider. 2/2

Comment: P.S. Also, it's generally good if you can avoid having a lot of boilerplate, but if you can't, then try and look at it in terms of what you get vs what it's going to cost you. If it looks like (or if it later turns out to be) something that you don't have to maintain and tweak a lot, then maybe it's fine. If it's something that requires constant attention from you and sort of often gets in your way, then perhaps there's an alternate design that would work better.

Comment: Thanks again, I'll definitely follow your advice. Actually I cannot narrow down the interface for `Algorithm`, I will need the new purely abstract base to inherit from the purely abstract bases of basic classes since in my code I manipulate an `Algorithm` as a `Coonfigurable` in a lot f places. But maybe there's hope for the decorator.

Comment: @FilipMilovanović: I think there is enough content in your comments for writing an answer.

Comment: I think there are two ways to solve this. First, as Filip points out, express the Algorithm as a pure virtual interface. If Algo inherits Configurable, that should be pure virtual as well. Alternatively, eliminate the configurable state. Pass this data via a concrete algorithm's constructor, or via the process() method.

Answer (score 4):

### If applying design patterns, avoid shortcuts

Your decorator is an incomplete one:

- The inheritance to the decorated class (`Component` in GoF terminology) is not for reuse its implementation, but to ensure compliance with its interface and substitutability.
- The implementation should forward **all** the operations to the decorated object.  Reusing the operation without forwarding is a shortcut that may in some cases work, but in most of the cases not, as your example shows.

GoF recommends therefore in particular:

> Components and decorations must descend from a common `Component` class.  It's important to keek this common class **lightweight**; that is, it should focus on **defining an interface**, not on storing the data. The definition of the **data representation should be deferred to the subclasses**.

This is exactly what the inheritance of `Configurable` breaks.

### Make your design work

The shared representation is a way to solve it.  A better way imho, would be to make `Configurable` abstract and without data, and use a `ConcreteConfigurable` as a strategy  for implementing the `Configurable` in you concrete algorithm (i.e. just forward the calls). The decorator would then use as strategy the algorithm it decorates, which is also a Configurable and is then guaranteed to use the same strategy with less boilerplate code (see [quick attempt](https://ideone.com/25Lbcu), but needs refinement).

A pragmatic workaround in your case, would be to make the operation of `Configurable` virtual and forward them in the decorator.  You'd then have a useless representation, but your decorator [decorates correctly](https://ideone.com/9Eulpu):

```
class AlgorithmDecorator: public Algorithm{
public:
  AlgorithmDecorator(std::unique_ptr<Algorithm> &&algo): _algo{std::move(algo)} {}
  void Process() { _algo->Process(); /* decoration code here */}
  void SetParameter(int i) override { _algo->SetParameter(i); }
  int GetParameter() override { return _algo->GetParameter(); }
protected:
  std::unique_ptr<Algorithm> _algo;
};
```

### Challenge

But is the decorator is really the best way for what you want to achieve?  If it's only about adding a couple of steps to the algorithm,  I wonder if an implementation of the [template method pattern](https://refactoring.guru/design-patterns/template-method) would not lead to a simpler design:

```
class Algorithm: public Configurable, public Named, public DataUser {
public:
  virtual ~Algorithm() = default;
  virtual void doBefore() {}
  virtual void doAfter() {}
  virtual void doProcess() = 0; 
  virtual void process() {
      doBefore(); 
      doProcess(); 
      doAfter();  
  }
};

class MyAlgorithm : public Algorithm {
public :
    void doProcess() override { std:cout<<"Do smothing"<<std::endl; }
};

class MyDecoratedAlgorith : public MyAlgorithm {
public :
    void doBefore() override { std:cout<<"Prepare more"<<std::endl; }
    void doAfter() override { std:cout<<"Do smothing more"<<std::endl; }
};
```

Comment: Thanks for your very detailed and complete answer. I'd need to take some time to go through it and s evaluate the applicability to my real case (which is more complex than that of the example). About the last point, I think I need the decorator since I want to be able to add behavior incrementally at runtime. But template methods and the NVI idiom sounds quite good to me so I'll see if I can go that way.